# How can i name Android app with using words like Facebook , Instagram

Tags: android

I built a Instagram image downloader app i named my app name  with video downloader for instagram.but playstore deletes my app because "Instagram" name is used. How to use word "Instagram " without app deleted.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "Instagram" Name. Don't use any trademarked app name If you do this then your app can be suspended.